# Opening a browser and filling in some data

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

i want to know how i can open a browser to a specific web page and then fill out some of the content of the boxes on that page.

My idea is for someone to be able to order a particular item from our internal ordering system. The barcodes for these items are what will populate the fields on the page i want to open.

I no i can open a new instance of ie using `Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", url);` howver how do i get a handle on that exact ie instance window so i can begin to add the required data to the fields?

Is this even possible?

Thanks very much

Comment: Is the target page under your control?

Comment: its on our internal network but i dont control it

Comment: I was going to suggest passing parameters in the querystring. If it's on the internal network, it might be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WatiN](http://watin.org/) should help with this.  I've generally used it for acceptance testing of web apps, but the principle is the same.  Open a browser instance, reference stuff in the DOM, manipulate form elements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [WatiN](http://watin.org/) (as was suggested in another answer), you might consider a load testing package like [Web Performance Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/).  They have a free version that lets you run up to 10 virtual users at a time, which will perform scripted actions.

Another option would be to use a standard WebBrowser object to load your website.  The WebBrowser object allows you to access and alter certain web parts.  Below is sample code that automatically searches Bing:

```
private void LoadPage()
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();

    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.bing.com");

    //Wait for document to load...
    while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    //Set the text of the search input
    HtmlElement txtTextField = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sb_form_q");
    txtTextField.InnerText = "My test text";

    //Perform a click on the search button
    HtmlElement btnSubmit = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("sb_form_go");
    btnSubmit.InvokeMember("click");

}
```